# Function of matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

Let $f(x):\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^+$ be a positive function.

Given a square matrix $A$, What can we say about the positive definiteness of
$f(A)$.

The function $f(A)$ is defined by replacing each $x$ in $f(x)$ by a matrix $A$.

Comment: $f$ is too generic: you can send almost anything to anything

Comment: In other words, absolutely nothing can be said !

Comment: A question with much more positive answers would be : if $A$ is pd (positive definite) is $f(A)$ still pd ?

Answer (score 0):

Nothing much in general. For instance, consider the positive function $f(x)=|x|$. You can easily find examples where $f(A)$ is indefinite.